# Android SearchView select all text on Honeycomb

Tags: java, android

I'd like to select all text on the SearchView content.

Is any way can set selection on the all text?

Comment: You should post the details of what you've tried.  If you haven't tried anything, then you're asking this question too soon.

Answer (score 0):

You can try in your xml layout file: android:selectAllOnFocus="true"